# Two divs in one don’t handle mouse events

Tags: javascript, html

A have a `div_main`, then I put one `div_child1` inside first `div_main` - child div handles mouse event; after, I put the second `div_child2` into `div_main`, and neither become handling mouse event, i.e. not `div_child1` not `div_child2` doesn’t react to mouse click or mouse move event. What to do?

```
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute;lef:0;top:60%;width:100%;height:40%;background: white;overflow-x:hidden"></div>
```

then in js code I execute the next operations(don't know how to say it properly in case of js :) ):

```
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML+='<div id="cntr-global" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:200%; overflow:hidden;height:100%;>'
document.getElementById("cntr-global").innerHTML+='<div id="cntr-main" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:50%; overflow:hidden;height:100%;>'
document.getElementById("cntr-global").innerHTML+='<div id="cntr-all" style="position:absolute;left:100%;top:0px;width:50%; overflow:hidden;height:100%;>'

for(;b_cnt<10;b_cnt++)
{
var sw=70;
btn[b_cnt]=new button("rgb(255,255,255)",b_cnt, choose_article,document.getElementById("cntr-main"),"2%",10+sw*b_cnt,"96%",sw,"white");
}
```

button class

```
var button = ES3Class({
constructor: function (color, id, func, parent, x, y, width, height, theme)
{
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

this.color = color;
this.func=func;

this.ph = document.createElement('div');
this.ph.style.position = 'absolute';
this.ph.style.background = color;
this.ph.style.width = width;
this.ph.style.height = height;
this.ph.style.left = x;
this.ph.style.top = y;

parent.appendChild(this.ph);

this.phm = document.createElement('div');
this.phm.style.position = 'absolute';
this.phm.style.background = color;
this.phm.style.width = this.ph.offsetWidth-2;
this.phm.style.height = this.ph.offsetHeight-2;
this.phm.style.left = '1';
this.phm.style.top = '1';

this.ph.appendChild(this.phm);


this.par=parent;
this.theme=theme;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.cx = width;
this.cy = height;

this.ph.onclick=function(){func(id);};
this.koef = 0;
},
SetPos: function (x, y) 
{
this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.ph.style.left = x;
  this.ph.style.top = y;
},
SetBound: function (x, y, cx, cy) 
{
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.cx = cx;
 this.cy = cy;
this.ph.style.width = cx;
this.ph.style.height = cy;
this.ph.style.left = x;
this.ph.style.top = y;
},
Text: function (text, id, tcolor, x, y, size, font) 
{
this.t=[0];
this.t[id] = document.createElement('p');
    this.t[id].style.position = 'absolute';
    this.t[id].style.color = tcolor;

    this. t[id].style.left = x;
    this. t[id].style.top = y;
    this. t[id].style.fontFamily=font;
    this. t[id].style.fontSize=size;

    this.phm.appendChild(this. t[id]);
    this. t[id].className="noselect";
    this. t[id].innerText=text;
 },
 Delete: function () 
 {
 this.ph.remove();
 },
 Image: function (src, x, y, width, height) 
 {
    this.im = document.createElement('div');
    this.im.style.position = 'absolute';

    this.im.style.left = x;
    this.im.style.top = y;
   this.im.style.width=width;
   this.im.style.height=height;
    this.im.style.background=src;
    this.im.style.backgroundSize='cover';
    this.phm.appendChild(this.im);
   },
   Ind: function(inde)
  {
 this.ph.style.zIndex=inde;
 }

  });

var btn=[0];
```

mousemove listener

```
function move_lis(e) 
{
  var i=0;
    for(;i<b_cnt;i++)
    {
        var el=btn[i];

        var x=e.pageX-el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        var y=e.pageY-el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        var kef=el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().width*2;
        if(el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().width>el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().height)
          kef=el.ph.getBoundingClientRect().height*2;

        if(el.theme=="dark")
        {
            el.ph.style.background="radial-gradient(circle "+kef+"px at "+x+"px "+y+"px, white, rgba(10,10,10,255)";
            el.ph.style.background="-ms-radial-gradient( "+x+"px "+y+"px, circle , white , rgba(0,0,0,0))";
        }
      else
      {
        el.ph.style.background="radial-gradient(circle "+kef+"px at "+x+"px "+y+"px, rgb(90,90,90), rgba(240,240,240,255)";
        el.ph.style.background="-ms-radial-gradient( "+x+"px "+y+"px, circle , rgb(60,60,60) , rgba(230,230,230,0))";
      }
    }

}
```

I’ve added onlick attribute to menu, click on button and menu’s onlick works. Seems like child elements are TRANSPARENT for mouse events.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? Usually it should work fine.

Comment: @ArmedinKuka added

Comment: @MarinTerziyski I’ve added a code

Comment: Yes, I saw it now and already delete my previous comment :)

Comment: Can you also include you javascript code for mouse events ?

Comment: @ArmedinKuka, it’s big, but ok

Comment: @ArmedinKuka added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting all `innerHTML`s before `for` loop it started work.
Also it works if to create element via document.createElement, even after button creation.

Web sucks, c++ rules

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to use `querySelectorAll` to add mouse events to your new `<div>`s.

If you will be adding and removing nodes with events, you should consider using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<div id="div_child1">Child 1</div>';
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<div id="div_child2">Child 2</div>';

for (let div of document.querySelectorAll('#main > div')) {
  div.addEventListener('click', handleMouse);
}

function handleMouse () {
  console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Actually I don’t want to use jQuerry

Comment: There's no query in my answer. querySelectorAll is an HTML5 API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Yeah, understand but the problem is, that I want to handle mouse move in any area of document, not only when it hovers the button. However, I don’t understand why the click() doesn’t work in my code

Comment: If you need  to handle mouse move in any area of document, then you should definitely use event delegation.

Comment: I found one interesting thing: the scroll bar in first child div is white(but in safari it’s always black).